# How to host REST Service along with an ASP.NET Core web site in same domain on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, grpc, iis-10

I want the be able to access a (REST) JSON Transcoding (HTTP/1) gRPC Service and an ASP.NET Core web site in the same IIS domain.

Either running two Different projects (if possible) where the gRPC Service is one project and the web site is in another .. or to be able to Combine the web site into one single project.

The gRPC server could/should use completely different ports than 80/443.

Several web sites on the server share the same ip so opening a port for gRPC would need to Only respond for that domain.

I notice that a gRPC Service code starts off Exactly like an ASP.NET CORE web application with

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

I can listen to a specific port for gRPC like this:

```
IPEndPoint ipEndPointHttps = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7153);

builder.WebHost.UseUrls($"https://{ipEndPointHttps }");
```

but that doesn't limit the listening to one domain - and it doesn't setup the web site to listen on 80/443?

In the future when upgrading to Windows Server 2022 from 2016 I'll convert to using HTTP/2 gRPC instead of REST.